# I am using createBrowserRouter. What is the proper way to have Header and Footer components render on every route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the start page in the Root component and I added the Header and Footer components wrapped in a div, but I don't know how to include them with the rest of the routes in the best way. Am I missing something or using the wrong approach?

Moreover, I am using createBrowserRouter instead of BrowserRouter since I am using data APIs as mentioned in the docs [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)

Here is my code:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Root />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    ),
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
  {
    path: '/products',
    element: <ProductsList />,
  },
  {
    path: '/products/:productId',
    element: <SingleProductPage />,
  },
])

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app'))
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

When I navigate to '/' the Header and Footer displays, but that's not the case for other routes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

React Router has a concept of [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes)
Basically it's a route without any path which doesn't participate in the URL matching.

> It only exists to make wrapping multiple child routes in the same layout simpler

In your example, you can declare a layout route like this :

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

function Layout() {
  return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Outlet />
        <Footer />
      </>
  );
}

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout/>,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [  
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Root />
      },
      {
        path: '/products',
        element: <ProductsList />
      },
      {
        path: '/products/:productId',
        element: <SingleProductPage />
      }
    ]
  }
])
```

Notice the presence of `<Outlet />` in the `Layout` component to display the child route.

Comment: just an addition, you import the `Outlet` component from react-router-dom. [Docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#the-root-route)

Comment: yes, the import is present in my answer. Is my import wrong ?

Comment: oh, sorry about that...i didn't see it.

Comment: It works, thanks! Should I include future routes as `children` of the `Layout` element?

Comment: yes if you want to display the header and footer in your future routes

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have the header and footer displaying always is because it's included in the route. In your case, keep the `createBrowserRouter` away from `<Header>` and `<Footer>`. Use a layout or something similar.

If you're using RouterProvider v6.9.0 - React Router, then what you can do is, have a layout component:

```js
const Layout = ({children}) => (
  <Header />
  {children}
  <Footer />
);
```

And use it this way:

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: (
      <Layout>
        <Root />
      </Layout>
    ),
    errorElement: <ErrorPage /></Layout>,
  },
  {
    path: '/products',
    element: <Layout><ProductsList /></Layout>,
  },
  {
    path: '/products/:productId',
    element: <Layout><SingleProductPage /></Layout>,
  },
]);
```

This is the most easiest method. You can also add this element here and send the path as children of that element:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Root />,
      },
      {
        path: "/products",
        element: <ProductsList />
      },
      {
        path: "/products/:productId",
        element: <SingleProductPage />
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

Comment: for me, using
` createBrowserRouter([ 
    {
        element: (<><MenuFloat /><Footer /></>),`
 was enough